# Error connecting to SQL Server using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I've been trying to connect to SQL Server using SQL Server Management Studio to no avail.

This is what the error says:

> Cannot connect to .\HAMED.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Login failed for user 'HAMED'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

I have an instance of SQL Server by the name of `Hamed` which is run in `Network Sevice` mode. I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you didn't grant yourself SQL admin during the install, but are you sure the DB instance is "HAMED"?  That sounds like the machine name.  Try connecting to .\sqlexpress

Do you remember the SA password?  If so, you can add yourself by logging in with that account.  Otherwise, you'll have to jump through some hoops and loops to get yourself added.

If you forgot to add yourself to the SQL admin group, read this article:

http://blogs.ameriteach.com/chris-randall/2009/12/11/sql-server-2008-forgot-to-add-an-administrator-account.html

Comment: The instance name is `Hamed` which is the same as the machine name. I try to connect to it by inputting `HAMED\Hamed` or `.\Hamed`. Nothing works. I'm getting to the point of frustration.

Comment: And also I have assigned my User to be the Database Engine admin during installation.

Comment: @EdwinDrood - When you attempt to connect, in the Server name drop down click "Browse for more".  It should provide you a list of valid instances on your local machine.  If you don't see your instance, open the "Windows Services" and make sure your instance is started.  If it says "Manual", change it to automatic and start the service.

Comment: I see my instance in the list. It's running.

Comment: @EdwinDrood - what did it say "Hamed\Hamed" ?  If that's the case, the current user logged in does not have rights.  Can you login with SA and add the current user?

Comment: Yes, it says `HAMED\Hamed` and also my user (`Hamed`) is an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use "SQL Server Authentication" in the login dialog in SSMS, but the user that you're trying to use is a Windows user/administrator? If so, the fix should be as simple as choosing "Windows Authentication" in the drop-down.

UPDATE: looks like I jumped the gun - [this sql server forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/c3e0713c-b4e6-400e-9ba2-448cd5bf3cb8/) lists lots of possible issues, including permissions issues, orphan users, etc.

Comment: Nope, your assumption is wrong. I choose `Windows Authentication`. I'll check that thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

sa... the answer was sa.

I had set the administrative password but didn't know the username to go with it.  Very nube, I know, you can hit me with it later.

When I installed SQL it asked me to set administrative password - right now SSMS can login.

Under users I see 1\cory (1 is my machine name - I'm trying a numbering scheme).  But if I type that in it fails with the error. SQL says "no, that's an NT login, I can't use those".

Under the users list SQL does in fact show the user as Windows authentication but as I said - for some reason I can't connect using Windows authentication.  The connection times out.

I'll just add a direct user name here.

All this is to do the MSVA courses for SQL certification.  First exam: get sql SSMS to work.